# Analyzing possible WordPress hacking

Tags: wordpress, security

I have just been checking the yearly stats for a blog I manage, and there is one post from 2008 that is getting a LOT of views, which doesn't make any sense as the info in it is outdated.

I pulled the access_log entries for this post and am finding a lot of referrers from cials-pills-online.info and sites like that.  Not a lot of entries for any one of these sites, but say 20-30 a month.

I have looked around the site and can't see anything obvious amiss.  Can anyone tell me where to look and what to look for to see if there's any monkey business related to this post?

Comment: Steve, up your "Accept answers rate" . You will get more attention to your post if its high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a rather simple way to see if it is really monkey business or not if you dont need it delete the post and resubmit it it really depends on the post what is it on maybe you just did  some great SEO or are ranking for a relative keyword. If they are leaving comments maybe its just for backlinks this happens when you have a post that is for example my site is on planes and i make a post on cars so I get people that want backlinks from a site on cars
There are also a lot of great security plugins just search in plugins

Comment: Yeah it's strange...nobody is leaving comments, and I can't find anything on my site that links to these outside sites. AFAIK it doesn't help with someone else's SEO to link to my site, so I can't figure out why they'd be doing it.

Comment: If it is someone linking to your site and its pointless like linking to a new site that has 5 pages yeah it wont help them but its a bot doing the linking its usually people that have no clue how to do SEO and just hire or subscribe to programs that make automatic backlinks